# как перебрать такой обьект?

Tags: reactjs

```
const pizza = {
  cap: {
    dough: 1,
    tomato_sauce: 1,
    onion: 2,
    sausage: 2,
    mashroom: 3,
    cheese: 1,
  },
  onions: {
    dough: 1,
    tomato_sauce: 1,
    onion: 2,
    meat: 1,
    cheese: 1,
  },
  king_one: {
    dough: 1,
    tomato_sauce: 1,
    onion: 2,
    mayo: 1,
    mashroom: 3,
    tomato: 2,
    cheese: 3,
    dill: 2,
    parsley: 2,
  },
  gavay: {
    dough: 1,
    tomato_sauce: 1,
    onion: 2,
    ananas: 1,
    cheese: 2,
  },
  tonno: {
    dough: 1,
    tomato_sauce: 1,
    tuna: 2,
    kappers: 1,
    cheese: 1,
  },
  vegeterian: {
    dough: 1,
    tomato_sauce: 1,
    tomato: 2,
    kappers: 1,
    cucumber: 2,
    onion: 2,
    cheese: 1,
  },
};
```

Comment: Подробнее опишите задачу, пожалуйста

Answer (score 0):

Например, так:

```
Object.entries(pizza).map(([type, items]) => {
  Object.entries(items).map(([item, count]) => {
    console.log(type, item, count)
  })
});
```

Но перебрать можно по разному, поэтому уточните что именно нужно сделать.